# import osm file to Neo4j 3.3.2

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I am new to neo4j & using neo4j version 3.3.2
neo4j spacial branch - 0.25-neo4j-3.3

Could you provide a code snippet to import osm file?

I have tried https://github.com/maxdemarzi/OSM .
Neo4j spacial ReadMe(Importing an Open Street Map file) example does not  work.

/Thanks

Comment: There is on chapter about that in https://www.amazon.com/Learning-Neo4j-3-x-performance-visualization/dp/1786466147/  

(spoiler: I wrote it)

Comment: Seems I have to buy the book to see your example :(

Answer (score 1):

You can just install the [Neo4j Spatial](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/0.24-neo4j-3.1/index.html#_get_started) plugin and run the cypher query for import:

```
CALL spatial.addLayer('layerTestName', 'osm', '')
CALL spatial.importOSMToLayer('layerTestName', '/path/to/file.osm')
```

Java example ([from doc](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/0.24-neo4j-3.1/index.html#spatial-import-osm)):

```
OSMImporter importer = new OSMImporter("/path/to/file.osm");
importer.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
BatchInserter batchInserter = getBatchInserter();
importer.importFile(batchInserter, "map.osm", false);
//batchInserter.shutdown();
//GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(databasePath);
reActivateDatabase(false, false, false);
GraphDatabaseService db = graphDb();
importer.reIndex(db);
db.shutdown();
```

Comment: I need to use Java

Comment: @user3478108 add example from the documentation for the neo4j spatial.